# Computer not starting up after GTX 1060 install

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios

i'm looking to replace my GTX 550ti with a GTX 1060. After replacing the 550ti with the 1060, the computer boots up with 1 of the fans spinning on the 1060.  I am able to see a HP startup screen saying press esc to enter the boot menu, but any keys I press do nothing and then the screen goes black eventually. I also hear a very short beep every 20-30 seconds from the motherboard.

My computer hardware is:

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz
- RAM: 16gb
- PSU: 600 watt
- Model: HP h9-1150t
- Motherboard: IPIWB-PB
- BIOS: AMI 7.10 2/23/2012
- BIOS Mode: Legacy

I have tried to search for a BIOS update on the HP website, but they provide only the HP support assistant software. I looked at trying to enable UEFI mode, but my BIOS does not give me an option to do so. I also know the GTX 1060 card is not faulty, because I was able to run it on another computer just fine. I also don't have integrated graphics on my CPU.

The graphics card itself is mounted on my PCI 2.0 x16 slot, and if I change the card back to the GTX 550ti everything is working again.

Comment: does the GPU have power connected? IIRC the 550 might be bus powered. the 1060 would not be

Comment: The 550 and 1060 both require a 6 pin cable, I plugged the same cable into the 1060 and I can see 1 of the fans spinning so I can confirm it has power.

Comment: If it wasn't getting enough power, the card would be screaming at you with its onboard speaker. I once forgot to connect one of the two PCI Express cables to my 1080 and I knew about it as soon as I hit the power button. Have you tried reseating the 1060?